# replace Floor tile mortar

Tags: tile

I removed a loose floor tile from kitchen floor and want to reuse it. Do I need to remove all the old mortar? If so, any tips?[image]

Comment: Do you have an oscillating tool?

Comment: Carefully scrape with a narrow *margin trowel*.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what's in your toolbox.  I'd cut along the grout line with an angle grinder with a diamond blade and then score a few checker board lines in the mortar and then chisel it up with a small cold chisel and a hammer.

Looks like a nice wood floor you used to have in your kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

For one small tile it isn’t worth trying to remove any mortar as you’ll risk loosening or damaging other tiles. Clean thoroughly, vacuum to remove dust, and glue it back into place with a polyurethane or epoxy adhesive.

I hope there is something protecting the edge of the tile that has been removed that we are not seeing in the photo?